# Get the length based on the column split in a dataframe in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column "remarks" which contains text. I want to add a new column by checking remarks column length. For example, If remarks column have length == 2, I need to take split($"remarks", " ")(1). otherwise I will take remarks column as it is.

ex: remarks = "xxxx yyyy", I am expecting count should be 2 and if it is the case I need to take yyyy as value in new column which we are adding.

Here is the code I have tried but not getting expected results.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("remarks1",when(length(split(col($"remarks")," ") === 2),col($"remarks").split(" ")(1)).otherwise(col($"remarks")))
```

With the above code, I am getting error:

*Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(split(`remarks`, ' ') = 2)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(split(`remarks`, ' ') = 2)' (array and int).;; 'Project [remarks#33, dv#37, dp#42, dv1#48, sig#55, en#63, es#72, CASE WHEN length((split(remarks#33,  ) = 2)) THEN split(remarks#33,  )[1] ELSE cefversion#33 END AS remarks1#107]*

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this.

Thanks,bab

Comment: Typo. It should be `when(length(split(col($"remarks")," ") === 2)` - note `===`, not `==`.

Comment: Hi  user10465355 , when I add ===, I am getting different error. Please see updated question. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: There is also at least one misplaced bracket, and two incorrect calls to `col` (argument should be string.

Comment: Could you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

I could able to narrow down the issue and here is the correct approach:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("remarks1", when(size(split($"remarks" ," ")) === 2,split($"remarks"," ")(1)).otherwise(col("remarks")))
```